# UICollectionView.reloadData() works after adding first item, then seems to run one behind

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, reloaddata

I have an empty UICollectionView with an array of strings as the datasource.

When I add the first string to the array and call reloadData() on the collectionView this  works as I would expect.  When I add a second string and call reloadData() nothing happens, but my array has definitely grown.  When I add a third item and call reloadData(), the second item appears but not the third.  Each new addition results in the previous string appearing.

If I then call reloadData() without adding a string, the last item then appears.

My code for adding to the collection:

```
func addKeyword(keyword: String) {

    keywords.append(keyword)
    newKeywordText.text = ""
    keywordCollection.reloadData()

}
```

And my collectionView relevant code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    print("keywords: at refresh \(keywords.count)")
    return keywords.count
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let keyword = keywords[indexPath.row]
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "KeywordCloudCell", for: indexPath) as! KeywordCloudCell
    let keywordLabel:UILabel = (cell.viewWithTag(1) as? UILabel)!
    keywordLabel.text = keyword

    return cell
}
```

I know that numberOfItemsInSection is returning the correct count, so I have no idea why its behaving this way.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to complete your array population first, and when it is completed then call 
   **keywordCollection.reloadData()**

can you also share on how you are calling the addKeyword method